# Selenium java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 3, size is 3

Tags: java, arrays, selenium, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

I am writing a selenium code to clear list of items that defined in a table.
clearing item by clicking delete icon. I am doing the following:

1- Read all items
2- Save them in array list of SelenideElement Array.
3- click on delete icon for each item row, by make a loop on the Arraylist.

Although I am using size limit of items in the Arraylist, there is **IndexOutOfBoundsException** generated!!

Still I don't know why! As code shown, we can't reach the index which exceed the Array size limit.
code is working well, items will be deleted unless the the number items reached 2! So why it was working but when the size getting decreased the code will caused an Exception!

My code:

```
List<SelenideElement> list_items = new ArrayList<>();
    for (SelenideElement Obj : $("#tableX").$$("tr")) 
        list_items.add(Obj.$$("td").get(4).$("a"));

    for (int t = 0; t < list_items.size();t++) {
        if (t < list_items.size()) {
            ((JavascriptExecutor) WebDriverRunner.getWebDriver()).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", list_items.get(t));
            WebDriverRunner.getWebDriver().manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(6,
            TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            WebDriverRunner.getWebDriver().navigate().to("https://url/tableItems");
            $$("a").shouldHave(sizeGreaterThan(1));

        }
    }
```

Error Log:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.impl.CollectionElement.getWebElement(CollectionElement.java:29)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.impl.SelenideElementProxy.dispatchAndRetry(SelenideElementProxy.java:85)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.impl.SelenideElementProxy.invoke(SelenideElementProxy.java:58)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.findElements(Unknown Source)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.impl.WebElementSelector.findElements(WebElementSelector.java:37)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.impl.BySelectorCollection.getActualElements(BySelectorCollection.java:28)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.impl.CollectionElement.getWebElement(CollectionElement.java:29)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.commands.ToWebElement.execute(ToWebElement.java:11)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.commands.ToWebElement.execute(ToWebElement.java:8)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.commands.Commands.execute(Commands.java:136)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.impl.SelenideElementProxy.invoke(SelenideElementProxy.java:52)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.toWebElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.impl.ElementFinder.getSearchContext(ElementFinder.java:69)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.impl.ElementFinder.getWebElement(ElementFinder.java:56)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.commands.GetWrappedElement.execute(GetWrappedElement.java:11)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.commands.GetWrappedElement.execute(GetWrappedElement.java:8)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.commands.Commands.execute(Commands.java:136)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.impl.SelenideElementProxy.dispatchAndRetry(SelenideElementProxy.java:82)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.impl.SelenideElementProxy.invoke(SelenideElementProxy.java:58)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.getWrappedElement(Unknown Source)
```

Please, Any help?

Comment: can you paste error log here.

Comment: @AbdulKhalid Please, could you see it.
I have posted it!